# Thunder Client: how to retrieve current request url?

Tags: web-api-testing, thunderclient

Is there a way to retrieve the current running request's url for scripting purposes?

in Postman, I could do:

`pm.request.url`

Is there a similar call under `tc` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can access url in Thunder Client - `tc.request.url`

See all properties and functions [available here](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/tc-types.d.ts)

Scripting docs - [click here](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md#custom-filters)